# Convert Series to Date

Tags: python, date, time-series

df have dates in the below format:

```
df:{'Date': ['09/11/2020','06/11/2020','02/11/2020','31/10/2020']}
```

The data type in `df.Date` is `pandas.core.series.Series`

I have used the code to extract day and month.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'].dt.month
```

Output is `09 06 02 10`

Desired output is `11 11 11 10`

How to get first two digits to recognise as day and next two digit as month?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give correct format for date.

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Output

```
df.Date. dt.month
> 11 11 11 10
```

Check the documentation of [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to read more about format.

Comment: Thank hadi k, I am still getting same i.e 09, 06,02 and 10 as months.

Comment: can you print your dataframe and show the output and what you tried exactly?

Comment: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(INdata.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')

df['Date'].dt.month

0      9
1      6
2      2
3     10
4     10
5      6
6      3
7      3
8      9
9      9
10     7
11     1
12     8
Name: Date, dtype: int64

Comment: what is INdata? Update your question to include the changes.

Comment: Is there an option to share the screen shot ?

Comment: INdata is datafame name

Comment: show the data that is in `INdata` and [you can insert images in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post) It is hard to diagnose a problem without knowing what is the code and how does the data looks like. Please create a  question so that it is reproducible. [Check the stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: let me create a question with the screenshot. Tks